# Comparing strings in typescript before compilation

Tags: typescript

I have been developing a package and I found out, that I'd love to show a problem (meaning something like the screenshot just with different message)

[image: 1]

when there is a wrong value passed to one of the functions.

I have a code that looks something like this:

```js
interface IEdge {
    id: string
}

interface IModule {
    id: string
    data: {
        inputEdges: IEdge[]
    }
}
const sampleModule = {
    id: "sampleModule",
    data: {
        inputEdges: [
            {
                id: "sampleEdge"
            },
            {
                id: "anotherEdge"
            }
        ]
    }
}

class Package {
    module: IModule|null = null
    init(module: IModule) {
        this.module = module
    }
    recieveOnEdge(
        edgeId: string,
        callback: any
    ){
       console.log(edgeId, callback)
    }
}

const packageInstance = new Package()
packageInstance.init(sampleModule)
packageInstance.recieveOnEdge("sampleEdge", "doesNotMatter")
```

I want to show an problem in editor, when first parameter of `.recieveOnEdge` is not one of the IDs of inputEdges property on `packageInstance.module`, but I don't know how to do so, as ID can be whatever string the developer desires.

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained [mre] that actually demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE?  Right now if I do so I get several errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: You'll need generic class, but I won't tell how until you minimal reproducible example

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, should be working fine now.

Comment: You will have a much better time if you use constructor arguments than use a separate `init()` step.  Why are you using `init` here?  What's the use of having a `Package()` that can sit around in an uninitialized state?

Comment: So [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2pKVm) shows the options as I see them.  The first option is to use constructor arguments and not `init()`; this is a straightforward generic class.  The second option is to make `init()` an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that narrows the type of the instance after it's constructed, but this is obnoxious to use (it requires a type annotation as shown).  Do these fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I'll most likely end up using constructor, otherwise up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the compiler to keep track of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to valid edge ids, we will need to make `Package` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those types, and all the types and interfaces that hold such ids should be generic as well.

Something like this:

```
interface IEdge<K extends string = string> {
    id: K
}

interface IModule<K extends string = string> {
    id: string
    data: {
        inputEdges: readonly IEdge<K>[]
    }
}
```

Here I've added the generic type parameter `K` to both `IEdge` and `IModule`.  If you don't specify them they will [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `string` like your version.  Also, when you create `sampleModule` the compiler will infer just `string` for those ids unless you give it a hint that it should pay closer attention, such as with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const sampleModule = {
    id: "sampleModule",
    data: {
        inputEdges: [
            {
                id: "sampleEdge"
            },
            {
                id: "anotherEdge"
            }
        ]
    }
} as const;
```

That `as const` causes the compiler to infer `sampleModule` as this type:

```
/* const sampleModule: {
    readonly id: "sampleModule";
    readonly data: {
        readonly inputEdges: readonly [{
            readonly id: "sampleEdge";
        }, {
            readonly id: "anotherEdge";
        }];
    };
} */
```

So now the compiler definitely knows that `"sampleEdge"` and `"anotherEdge"` are valid edge ids.  Also note that `inputEdges` has been inferred as a [`readonly` array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), which is technically wider than a read-write array.  That's why I widened the type in `IModule<K>` to `readonly IEdge<K>[]`.  That probably won't matter unless you need to start modifying that array after the fact (but I hope you don't, since that could change which edge ids are valid).

---

To make this easy, I'm going to replace your `init()` method with a constructor argument.  That way, the type of your package instance can know about the edge ids from the moment it's created. Otherwise we'd have to try to narrow the type when you call `init()`, which is hard to do properly.  You can technically do it by making `init()` an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), but it's not fun.  Unless someone needs to have a package instance sit around before it's initialized, we should have the initialization done in the constructor, which is more conventional anyway.

Here it is:

```
class Package<K extends string> {
    constructor(public module: IModule<K>) { }
    recieveOnEdge(
        edgeId: K,
        callback: any
    ) {
        console.log(edgeId, callback)
    }
}
```

So you can see that `receiveOnEdge()` only takes an `edgeId` of type `K`.  Let's test it out:

```
const packageInstance = new Package(sampleModule);
// const packageInstance: Package<"sampleEdge" | "anotherEdge">
```

So the compiler infers that `packageInstance` is of type `Package<"sampleEdge" | "anotherEdge">`, leading to the behavior you wanted with `receiveOnEdge()`:

```
packageInstance.recieveOnEdge("sampleEdge", "doesNotMatter"); // okay
packageInstance.recieveOnEdge("badEdge", "doesNotMatter"); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3&ssl=27&ssc=28&pln=26&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEAmBzCAeAaWQgA9IRMBnZSsKUbZAXhroYD5kBvAKAEhgmAFzICPAL48eoSLEQpUAWQD2mAK4AbfEVLkqreiEYtah7J14DhBhv0xwwcEZYEgADmrBZclEVAhwmMogGgCeaN7a7ADaALr8kpIIwbQ0cAC2bloq6lrM3PyCIgBElBlZEDmaEMUANHYOTgV8rh5eOBC+yNH8LS4tRcil5VqRxb184vUtfP1WJXAgymAAFtBjE5It8ZMSyHDUySC0PAD0AFTIR6llmdmq1c48yC-I-oHBYciDw3eVD1pigBuZ6vd5BELheyOJ6vOFvAIQr6gNqRLrgz7haK8eG4hEfSHfay-CpjEF45BTAoUuEYwk-RbLNZQMmg3HiWLk17iEHiZDnU5SBAaA7UAAKiAA1nBcIRiGQIBRqKYOM1rnQ1AgwMooAAKDwAIw0wAQyHSAIgIiUFsI7AAlNxKfx-AhgBAAG4QADyIEiut6EA6qGsBGmfAQcA0GgNUpEi1C-AdLmuyi0ADoNMpsLrA7hg7UrpHo1K7QkJEKUmBkG4pTKIKhjo4QEh8iAIAB3ZAShDS3C624VKpaO0g06nK6V6u1vONxZIETd3v4EmjDrFZAAHyGjNW6zX7CkNZ7dYbtDnEDTLrdnp9fpXEDGBeKQU6ADllooHLJiiPkGPkMo0oJkeS6nk2SCXhAroet6vodLqxQxpgj5DC+lDvmAn5gN+v7-tAUA6jwQA)